# call NSDictionary in current view controller

Tags: iphone

i have an function in which i am calling values from dictionary that is defined in other view controller. I have to call this method in view didload method of current view controller.

here is my code:

```
-(void)setData:(NSDictionary *)dic {

self.jsonLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"Description"];
self.jsonImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [dic objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]]];}
```

Comment: Question is how to call setData method in view didload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]];
```

**Update:**

See you allocate the dictionary while the second View controller inside its `alloc` `init` method.
Then you can pass the dictionary from the first view controller as

```
secondViewController.dict = self.dict;
```

Then you push the second view controller. Check the value of the dictionary in `viewDidLoad:` Then you can proceed if the dictionary is available.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//make sure jscontroller is allocated before this point.
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
// set tempDict here with value or object aBook.PictureURL.
jscontroller.jsonItem = tempDict;
[tempDict release];
 NSLog(@"json ndic.......%@", jscontroller.jsonItem);
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:jscontroller animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `viewControllerObject` is the necessary object of the view controller that defines this function then allocate the object and call like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[viewControllerObject setData:urDict];

}
```

Comment: as Dictionary is defined in otherViewcontroller here in currentViewController It is showing error that it is undeclared dictionary

Comment: Obtain the dictionary in this view controller by passing it to this view controller before pushing to this view or showing this view

Comment: I was using    [self setData:dic];
in CurrentViewController(self) where setData is method defined in currentViewController(self) ......

Comment: how can i obtain dictionary in this view controller i am trying but not successful

Comment: create a class variable of type NSDictionary and assign it the value of the dictionary in the other view controller before pushing the view or showing it.

Comment: i have done that like this:    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { jscontroller.jsonItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [jscontroller.jsonItem setValue:aBook.PictureURL forKey:@"PictureURL"];
 NSLog(@"json ndic.......%@", jscontroller.jsonItem);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:jscontroller animated:YES];}      how to call the value of 'jscontroller.jsonItem' in jscontroller in download method???

Comment: If jsonItem is a member of the class jscontroller you can easily call it by "jsonItem". There is no issue in that. Its just like calling any other member of the class.

Comment: yes, 'jsonItem' is a dictionary in jscontroller. When i called 'jsonItem' in my method and passing it in to NSURL then, it is giving exception. code:           -(IBAction) download{
 jsonItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonItem];
 NSLog(@" Nsurl..... %@", jsonURL);}         exception:-[NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ..
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.. 
2011-03-11 10:49:01.803 XML[703:20b] Stack: ()

Comment: jsonItem is a dictionary and u cannot pass a dictionary as NSString. NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonItem]; is wrong because jsonItem is not a string

Comment: my second answer will help you in this

Comment: i am not getting you!! i have pass the value in 'jscontroller.jsonItem' through [jscontroller.jsonItem setValue:aBook.PictureURL forKey:@"PictureURL"];  in '- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath'- method of class, from where i am pushing to jscontroller and need to use the value in 'download method' of jscontroller, where as jsonItem is dictionary in jscontroller.

Comment: how can i pass the key value jscontroller.jsonItem to nsurl in my download method!! help me?

Comment: If you see my second answer you will get the url from the dictionary which u can use in your download method

Comment: r u saying about second comment or  (void)viewDidLoad {

[viewControllerObject setData:urDict];

}

Comment: no my second answer saying this NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]];

Comment: going null at there :(                                        Nsurl..... (null)
2011-03-11 12:25:26.603 XML[1755:20b]  Nsurl..... (null)    -(IBAction) download
{
 NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]; 
 NSLog(@" Nsurl..... %@", jsonURL);
 /* UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL]];
 NSLog(@"%f,%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
 [image release]; */
   
}

Comment: Are you getting the jsonItem in this method. nslog() and check if jsonItem contains any values

Comment: yes!! i am just checking that do i get the value of jsonitem. but its not getting from controller where i am pushing to the jscontroller.

Comment: can you specify where actualy i have to insert code :econdViewController.dict = self.dict;

Comment: i am getting the value in viewdidload method but still it is showing null value in NSURL in 'download' method .  code:  NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]; 
 NSLog(@" Nsurl..... %", jsonURL);

Comment: ok did u get the dictionary in didLoad? Whats does it contain?

Comment: yes!!!   code:   - (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSLog(@"       url value ...%@",jsonItem);}                in gdb:      2011-03-11 13:53:18.275 XML[2374:20b]        url value ...{
    PictureURL = "\n    http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/mostlycloudy.gif";
}

Comment: ok try NSLog(@"url value %@", [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]); And why is '\n' there in the url?

Comment: i was also observing that why '\n' is occuring in key value!! even it doenot appear in my XML...

Comment: Pls cross check i think that may be the problem. did u get the nslog for the one i sent you in my previous comment

Comment: NSLog(@"url value %@", [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]);   is working in my download method..but why it is not getting in NSURL

Comment: Does the url contain \n? I thnk thats the problem. Pls cross-check again

Comment: this is not an issue ,i think because in NSLog(@"url value %@", [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]); in download method it is only showing url.its ok!! no problem with it. but thing is to get key value in nsurl..

Comment: Then NSUrl *url = [NSUrl urlWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]; should work. pls make sure that [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"] is a string and not NSUrl. Can you try NSUrl *url = [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"];

Comment: NSUrl *url = [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]; this works!! now everything is working!! thanku so much!!

Comment: Thats was the problem, the element u passed to the dictionary was of type NSUrl. So it wont work if its passed as string. Happy coding :) Pls vote up and accept the answer if u got it working

Comment: how to accept n vote? m a new bee!! :) i jst tick the answer n turn it into green!! oh! it require 15 reputation!!

Comment: just click the tick mark below the answer corresponding to the one that helped you and click on the up arrow button. Both can be found on the left side of the answers

Comment: right now i can only thanks you . i have not so much reputation that i can vote!! someday i will earn that reputation and tick yours answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was using this code in otherviewcontroller

and trying to retrieve in currentViewController

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
 {
JSONViewController *controller = [[JSONViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JSONView" bundle:nil];
EmpDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[EmpDictionary setValue:aBook.Description forKey:@"Description"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:aBook.PictureURL forKey:@"PictureURL"];
[EmpDictionary setValue:aBook.WeatherID forKey:@"WeatherID"];
EmpArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[EmpArray addObject:EmpDictionary];
NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = [self.EmpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller setData:itemAtIndex];}
```